# how to set a method only if a checkbox is selected?

Tags: android, checkbox, onclick

That's a tricky one.

I have two checkboxes and I would like to attach some text to a string depending on whether the checkboxes are clicked.
E.G. if checkbox1 is clicked, it adds "A" to the string "result"
if checkbox2 is clicked, it adds "B" to the string "result"

I tried several different methods and apparently the closest one is onClick.

```
final CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    checkBox1.setChecked(false);

    checkBox1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
                builder.append(value1).append("\n");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "item selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                builder.append("");
            }
        }
    });

    final CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox2.setChecked(false);

    checkBox2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
                builder.append(value2).append("\n");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "item selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                builder.append("");
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried also the onChangedState or something like that, but it does not work for my purpose.

Following a normal behaviour, if I click once, I append "A" and if click twice, I append "".
Yet, if I click three times, I append "A" "A", and not only "A".

Any idea on how to address this nuisance? probably some true/false statement?

Comment: I though of
else
builder.setLength(builder.length() - 5);

BUT
(1) what if I don't click twice on the same checkbow? e.g. I click on checkbox1, then on checkbox2, then I click again on checkbox1 in order to untick it: would it delete the append generated by Checkbox1 or Checkbox2?

(2) what if the length is variable? I cannot erase -5 if the length is 6 or higher

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
CheckBox Check = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Finalizado);
            boolean isChecked =  Check.isChecked();

if(isChecked)
{
   //doStuff...
}
else
{
  //doAnotherStuff...
}
```

Comment: Olà Thiago, why would the rootView help out?

Comment: i used this code in a fragment the rootview is the view inflated  in the oncreateview method sorry about that....